# Does Oracle Database do a full table scan even when using "WHERE ROWNUM = 1"?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Microsoft SQL Server, we can use following query to return the first row matching the condition:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MYTABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%next%'
```

In Oracle Database, we can use the `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` clause to achieve the same thing:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%next%' AND ROWNUM = 1
```

My question is, is Oracle Database smart enough to stop scanning the table after the first record matching the condition is found?

Basically, can I be assured that Oracle is employing some kind of short-circuit evaluation when using ROWNUM?

Comment: `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is the current Oracle way. I'd be surprised if Oracle didn't stop after the first row.

Comment: I presume you mean, will adding `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` to the query help in the case where you're already committed to a full scan because of the unindexed `LIKE '%next%'` bit? I imagine you could determine that via an `EXPLAIN` query both ways.

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler knowing that there will only ever be one single record that matches a condition is a common scenario. For example, if you have a table that holds configuration key/values for your application, you only want to fetch the first value with the matching key. If you don’t limit the query then the database will unnecessarily scan the table for other matching records, even though you only care about the first one. If you execute many of these queries back-to-back it could become a performance issue without limiting the result set

Comment: @user3163495 The point is there's no "first one". Without the ORDER BY clause the query can return multiple matching rows in any order, and this order is subject to change without notice. You may have been lucky to get the row you wanted, but that's not going to last.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think we are conflating two definitions of the word "first" here. When I use the word "first" I am referring to the first matching record that the database stumbles across as it scans the table, regardless of whether it's in an ORDER BY clause. When you use the word "first" you are referring to the context of an ordered list of records, where the "first" record would be record #1 in that list. There is absolutely a "first one" when the database is just searching for records that match the condition in the query in the absense of an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to generate a query and see.

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id   NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, name)
SELECT LEVEL, 'next'
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE();
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%next%' AND ROWNUM = 1
```

May output:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 526 | next |

And, if you look at the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the query:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%next%' AND ROWNUM = 1;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> Plan hash value: 1231656364
>  
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation          | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |         |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |         |       |       |            |          |
> |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTABLE |  1000 | 20000 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  
> Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
> ---------------------------------------------------
>  
>    1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
>    2 - filter("NAME" IS NOT NULL AND "NAME" LIKE '%next%')
>  
> Note
> -----
>    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
> ```

So the answer to your question:

> is Oracle Database smart enough to stop scanning the table after the first record matching the condition is found?

Yes, it will stop when it reaches the required count.

If you have other queries where you are confused what the behaviour may be then generate an `EXPLAIN PLAN` and look at what the database is actually going to use.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vAl1AeGw)